# sudo and su hang indefinitely... stumped

Tags: centos, sudo, su

I am trying to run `su` or `sudo` on my CentOS 6.6 machine. Every time I try to execute either command, I get prompted for a password. After entering the password, the command simply hangs. I can ctrl+c it. I have already checked my `/etc/hosts` and added the `$HOSTNAME` to the `127.0.0.1` and `::1` line. I can login in as root with a hassel. I tried running `strace` on `sudo` (`strace -o ~/sudotrace.txt sudo -i`) and got following error:

`sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

Doing an `ls -l`

`14 $ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x. 1 root root 123832 Oct 15  2014 /usr/bin/sudo`

These permissions seems to be wrong according to what I read online. That still doesn't explain why `su` behaving strangely though.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding the error message, it could simply be that running under strace doesn't allow sudo to switch UIDs (it's not clear whether you ran strace after logging in as root). To clarify, does `sudo -i` ask for a password and then hang? What about `sudo date`, does that properly print the time after asking for a password?

Comment: Those `sudo` permissions are a little weird, but not wrong. If you log in as root, and then run sudo (as root), does it hang? If so, you can use `strace` as root.

Comment: Also, how long have you tried waiting? Have you tried giving it 5 or 10 minutes, to make sure it isn't just a few network timeouts? (E.g., maybe you have LDAP configured and the LDAP server is down.)

Comment: No LDAP server or anything like that. It is a pretty basic setup. I was worried about the DNS server not responding, but then the login in general should be slow as well. The longest I have waited is ~5 min.

Comment: Also, run sudo, find its pid with `ps aux|grep sudo` and strace that with `strace -f -p PID` (might be difficult since you have to be root for that already). This behaviour reminds me of nfs issues (but there  is probably no reason to have nfs mounted somewhere under `/root`).

Comment: When running `strace` on the PID it get: `Process 8913 attached
read(4,`
There is so network file system mounted. Everything is local.

Comment: After ~20 min it finally completed, but didn't print anything out. `strace` gave this output:
`read(4,

0x7ffffb8a201f, 1)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=0, ptr=0x100000000}} ---`

Comment: Check `/var/log/secure` and `dmesg` to see any issues with `sudo`, also when you run `strace` and if it's waiting on `read(fd#`, - try running `lsof -p <PID>` to see the files opened

Comment: Is there a secondary authentication set up in Pam?